# When Butch walks back to his apartment, what is the radio in the background saying about Jackrabbit Slim's?

Tags: pulp-fiction

[image]

At around 1:28 in *Pulp Fiction*, as Butch walks past this random house on his way to get the gold watch back from his apartment, a radio can be heard in the background. The only part of the broadcast I can make out is "This is the Jackrabbit Slim's..."

This seems potentially significant since, chronologically speaking, Mia and Vincent did visit Jackrabbit Slim's before these scenes with Butch. But nobody died or overdosed on heroin or did anything else illegal at that diner that I can recall, so I don't know why its name would come up on the radio. Do we know what the rest of the broadcast said, or what off-screen incident it could be referring to?

Comment: According to a common legend, it's a report saying the trophy was stolen, hence Mia and Vince never won it. I've yet to confirm it, though (it made it to CNN, FWIW - see no. 19 [here](http://edition.cnn.com/2014/09/23/showbiz/movies/pulp-fiction-20th-anniversary/)). Couldn't make out any other words in the film itself, and in my opinion it's simply a commercial for the diner.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a commercial for Jack Rabbit Slims.  If you listen very closely, the announcer says "...and $5 milk shakes! Visit Jack Rabbit Slims nearest you..."
Tarantino loves making references to other scenes in his movies through little things such as these.

Comment: I think you're right. I just listened to it with the volume **WAY** up, and it does sound like "...five dollar shake(s). Visit the Jack Rabbit Slims nearest you, and (every other day??)"

Comment: I just happened to hear this for the first time today -- no way I would have heard it in a theatre: this is an advantage of video version. I searched for someone else who had heard this because it is very faint. Imagine that no one except for the film makers themselves knew about this for years after the film's initial release. You could easily miss it even if watching quietly at home.